# Loading data from a database to a Handsontable grid

Tags: c#, handsontable

I am using the following code to get data from my database and send to my handsontable grid.

```
      public JsonResult getACLog()
    {
        var log = new List<ACLog>();
        
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT fldPrimaryKey, fldCall, fldDateStr, fldTimeOnStr, fldMode, fldState, fldRstR, fldRstS, fldBand FROM tblContacts;");
        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)};dbq=C:\\Users\\User\\MasterLog.mdb;defaultdir=C:\\Users\\User;driverid=25;fil=MS Access;filedsn=C:\\Users\\User\\MasterLog.mdb.dsn;maxbuffersize=2048;maxscanrows=8;pagetimeout=5;safetransactions=0;threads=3;uid=admin;usercommitsync=Yes"))
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var logger = new ACLog();

                    logger.box = "false";
                    logger.fldPrimaryKey = (reader.SafeGetInt(0).ToString());
                    logger.fldCall = reader.SafeGetString(1);
                    logger.fldDateStr = reader.SafeGetString(2);
                    logger.fldTimeOnStr = reader.SafeGetString(3);
                    logger.fldMode = reader.SafeGetString(4);
                    logger.fldState = reader.SafeGetString(5);
                    logger.fldRstR = reader.SafeGetString(6);
                    logger.fldRstS = reader.SafeGetString(7);
                    logger.fldBand = reader.SafeGetString(8);
                    

                    log.Add(logger);
                }
            };
        }
        //return log;
        return Json(log, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When I do a debug session, it shows all the correct data in the log variable but my I get a popup box saying "localhostXXXX says error". Is my code correct or is the problem with the handsontable?

Not sure what to do.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do? Are you just trying to load the Handsontable from a database? If so, there is another way to do this that I find works easily.